# AWS CloudWatch Composite Alarms: Send Alert When 1 Alarm Has been "In Alarm" For Over a Certain Amount Of Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

So I'm trying to setup composite alarms on AWS. So far, I have most of it set up. At the moment, I have a composite alarm set up with 3 alarms. If any 2 of these 3 alarms trigger, then the composite alarm also triggers. This part works fine.

However, I am having trouble with part of my use case. I'd also like to make it so that if one of these alarms within the composite alarm stays in alarm for over a certain period of time, then an alert is also sent out.

Here's an example of the situation:

2 out of the 3 alarms turn on in any time period: Alert should be sent

1 out of the 3 alarms turn on for under a certain time period: Alert should not be sent

1 out of the 3 alarms turn on for over a certain time period: Alert should be sent

I've tried looking into the settings available on the alarms themselves, and there doesn't seem to be an option for what I'm trying to do.

I'm wondering if this would require a lambda function? Is it possible for a lambda function to keep track of how long an alarm has been in alarm?

Comment: So why do you need a composite alarm if one of them should inform you when the alarm is on?

Comment: It should only inform me if one of the single alarms is on for over a certain time period. So let's say the alarm goes on and then off in a pretty short time period, I don't want it sending alerts in that case. However, if the single alarm stays in alarm for a long time, that could indicate a problem to look into, and I'd like it to send an alert. I'm not looking to just send an alert whenever the alarm is on but rather when it's on for over a certain time period. If it's possible to configure this on the single alarm that works fine too.

Comment: Why not just adjust the time period for your alarms, so they don't go on/off in a short period of time, but only alarm when the metric being tracked is over the threshold for a longer period of time?

Comment: I've updated to post with more context. Anyways, let's say I have a composite alarm where I want it to activate when 2 single alarms turn on. If I edit the single alarms to not turn on in a short period of time, I'm not getting alerts from the composite alarm when I should. If 2 alarms turn on in a short period of time I want to be notified. However if only one turns on, I want to be notified only if it's been on for over a longer time period.

Comment: You would need 2 alarms for this. One composite and the other one should be with bigger time period as Mark said earlier.

Comment: So basically I need the composite alarm with all the single alarms in it, as well as duplicates of those single alarms that send their own notifications just for a longer time period?

Comment: I think I am wrong here. You can put some logic to composite alarms. I need to check it.

Comment: The logic in composite alarms seems very limited. You can only check combinations and states of alarms, not how long they've been on or anything. Obviously I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require duplicating every single alarm in the composite alarm, which is why I think I may need to write custom code to have this functionality.

Comment: You can put some logic to it. https://ibb.co/Jzc878C you can find an example. You can set different time period for both alarms. Don't create 'Composite alarm' but create an alarm with two or more metric and add 'Math' to it.

Comment: This might work, how would I go about making certain metrics go over the threshold for testing? In composite alarms I can manually trigger each alarm within it, but I can't seem to find anything for modifying metrics manually to make sure the alarm works as expected. Also if you put this math metric solution as an answer I'll accept it, seems like the best solution for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As talked in the comment section above, I am providing you with a possible solution to your problem. The only blocker is that you can't have different time frame for the alarms, both should be the same.

So you will have (example)- Alarm 1(cpu) if for 15 min it's over 60%. Alarm 2(EFS connections) if for 15 min there are more than 10 connections.

Now the alarm will go off when both the statements are true. Also the alarm will go off when only Alarm 1 goes off.

This is how you are going to make this alarm.

[image]

As for testing, it depends on what type of alarms you are making. For example cpu and ram increment methods are widely available on stackoverflow.

Also with `aws cli` you can change state of an alarm. It's usually for a very small amount of time, maybe 10 seconds.

```
aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state --alarm-name "myalarm" --state-value ALARM --state-reason "testing purposes"
```

You need to find a method which can suite your needs better.